# Nested Query Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this beautiful Json , and I'm trying with the powerful mongodb query to get all comments with file_id 12....so this is what I would like have back [4,5,7,10,11,15].

I tried with this query but the file_id it's completely ignored by the engine:

```
db.collection.distinct("changes.comments",
        {"my_uuid":"bf48e757-1a65-4546-bf24-2bb001effddd",
         "changes":{$elemMatch:{file_id:12}} } 
)
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5342bf796b03d7ffc834afcc"),
    "my_uuid" : "bf48e757-1a65-4546-bf24-2bb001effddd",
    "changes" : [ 
        {
            "file_id" : 12,
            "version" : 1,
            "comments" : [ 
                4, 
                5, 
                7
            ],
            "lastseen" : 1394640549
        }, 
        {
            "file_id" : 12,
            "version" : 2,
            "comments" : [ 
                10, 
                11, 
                15
            ],
            "lastseen" : 1394640511
        }, 
        {
            "file_id" : 234,
            "version" : 1,
            "comments" : [ 
                100, 
                110, 
                150
            ],
            "lastseen" : 1394640555
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to achieve what you what.  Although the query looks complex for what you are trying to do, it's simple once you get a hang of it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Get only documents where "my_uuid" equals "bf48e757-1a65-4546-bf24-2bb001effddd"
    {"$match":{"my_uuid":"bf48e757-1a65-4546-bf24-2bb001effddd"}},
    // Unwind the "changes" array
    {"$unwind":"$changes"},
    // Get only elements of the "changes" array where "file_id" equals 12
    {"$match":{"changes.file_id":12}},
    // Unwind the "comments" array
    {"$unwind":"$changes.comments"},   
    // Group by _id and add the comments to array only if not already present
    {"$group":{_id:"$_id", comments:{$addToSet:"$changes.comments"}}},
    // Cleanup the output
    {"$project":{_id:0, comments:1}}
])
```

Output:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "comments" : [
                                4,
                                5,
                                7,
                                10,
                                11,
                                15
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

**EDIT:** Including `my_uuid` in the results is fairly straight-forward.  We just need to group by `my_uuid` instead of `_id`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"my_uuid":"bf48e757-1a65-4546-bf24-2bb001effddd"}},
    {"$unwind":"$changes"},
    {"$match":{"changes.file_id":12}},
    {"$unwind":"$changes.comments"},   
    {"$group":{_id:"$my_uuid", comments:{$addToSet:"$changes.comments"}}},
    {"$project":{_id:0, my_uuid:"$_id", comments:1}}
])
```

Comment: can you provide me an example with my_uuid as unique and one not?

Comment: since we are already matching by `my_uuid`, it probably makes sense to group by `my_uuid` instead of `_id`.  i've updated my post with edited query.  this would work irrespective of whether `my_uuid` is unique or non-unique

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no straight forward way of pulling out only the matching document from an array. The  $elemMatch operator will only ensure that at least one of the documents within the array satisfies the condition provided by you. The query will however, always return the entire document. One way to achieve what you are looking for is -

```
db.sample4.aggregate({$unwind:"$changes"},{$match:{"changes.file_id":12}},{$project:{"changes.comments":1,"_id":0}});
```

These topics are covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array) in stackoverflow, where map-reduce approach as well is listed to achieve this. If the requirement was to return the first matching document, the you could have projected using `changes.comments.$:1` Eg. - `db.sample4.find({"changes":{$elemMatch:{"file_id":12}} },{"changes.comments.$":1} )`